# How to extract the second half of a word with an odd character length

Tags: python

I am trying to make a translator:

- If the length of the word is odd, it swaps the second half of the word, keeping the character in the middle in its position, with the first half.
- If the length of the word is even, it swaps the second half of the word with the first.

**How do I make it so that I can swap the second half of a word (keeping the middle character in its position that it was before) with the first?**

```
phrase = input("Phrase: ")

if len(phrase.split()) > 1:
    WORDS = phrase.split()

    if len(WORDS[0]) % 2 != 0:
        print(WORDS[0][-(len(WORDS) / 2 - 1):])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word = "abcde"
if len(word) % 2 != 0:
    print(word[len(word) // 2 + 1:] + word[len(word) // 2] + word[:len(word) // 2])
else:
    print(word[len(word) // 2:] + word[:len(word) // 2])
```

Output:

```
"decab" # for word = "abcde"
"cdab" # for word = "abcd"
```

If you want to keep the `c` with `ab` then you only need one line regardless of if it is odd or even:

```
word = "abcde"
print(word[len(word) // 2 + 1:] + word[:len(word) // 2 + 1])
```

Output:

```
"deabc"
```